# Using “in between” as an adverb

Tags: meaning-in-context, adverbs, idiomatic-language, prepositional-phrases, adverbial-phrases

Can we use “in between” when talking about something between two things when those two things are not specified? Example: Let’s
say I am watching this [video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=UB6iFw7V25Q)
with a friend of mine. Can I say, **“The cat is so confident because of the glass in between”** to my friend?

I wonder if that sentence would be correct because according to Collins Dictionary, ”in between” is used as an adverb when we are talking about something between one **specified** thing and another. See the 6th definition in the British English section [here.](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=UB6iFw7V25Q) Those things are not verbally specified in my example context, but my friend beside me sees that the glass is between the cat and the bear. Do you think we can use, “in between,” like I did in my sentence?

Comment: You could say it but I think _in between them_ would sound much better.

Comment: It's fine, but it's a preposition phrase, not an adverb, functioning as modifier of the noun "glass".

Comment: @BillJ I think the sentence I the sentence I gave can be said conversationally.

Comment: If my mother and my sister were having an argument, and I could see both sides (or neither side), I could say conversationally, 'I'm caught in between' but I am implying 'them' (which I would use in a more formal context).

Comment: @FireandIce It's fine in any context. The object of "between" is ellipted but recoverable from elsewhere, overt or implied, in the discourse.